# What is the preferred method of running background tasks in IsolatedAsyncioTestCase?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm using pytest 5.4.3 to run asynchronous unit tests.

Typically I like to run an isolated server instance and perform the unit test cases together with the spinned up server. Currently I'm trying to perform asynchronous unit tests, running a uvicorn server instance.

Anywhere else, I'd use **`asyncio.gather`** for running tasks in parallel, but `asyncSetUp` method forces the use of `run_until_complete`, as seen in `_callAsync` implementation in `lib/python3.8/unittest/async_case.py:74`.

Any long-running task will therefore make the unit test stuck on beginning, until `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised. The interrupt, indeed, stops the server instance and continues to perform the individual test cases.

Using `asyncio.create_task` to schedule the coroutine on the loop will on the other hand freezes the process completely and needs to be killed. The code used in this case follows:

```py
class HttpTestCase(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def asyncSetUp(self):
        ...
        self.task = uvicorn.Server(server_config).serve()
        asyncio.create_task(self.task)
```

I've also noticed that it depends on the implementation of the long-running task. For example, running a `aiocoap` server instance works perfectly well, because the coroutine will finish after the server start and handles the running in the background itself:

```py
class CoapTestCase(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def asyncSetUp(self):
        ...
        self.server = await aiocoap.Context.create_server_context(...)

    async def asyncTearDown(self):
        await self.server.shutdown()
```

What is the correct way to achieve having long-running tasks in background and continue with unit testing? Running the server in separate thread/process is always an option, but I'd be interested in figuring out how to do this using just asyncio.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: `asyncio.gather()` is a coroutine itself and can be used as an argument for `run_until_complete()`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Since there is no access to the task of performing the rest of test cases in the `asyncSetUp` method, gathering won't help here, I think.